# Wiring Home Alarm Motion Sensors into a Micro Controller

Tags: pcb-design, best-practice

I have approx. 25 motion detectors designed to be wired into a traditional home alarm system. They take 12V DC and have two built-in switches that open when events occur. One switch opens when motion is detected and closes when there is no motion, and another switch opens when a tamper condition is detected (cover removed, sensor covered with tape, etc.) and closes when there is no tamper condition.

There is J-Y(St)Y 8x2x0.6 mm wiring throughout that is to be used with the motion detectors and ends up in my basement. The wires are up to 160ft long. 2 pairs of 2 wires will deliver 12V DC. This leaves 1 pair for the motion switch circuit and 1 pair for the tamper switch circuit.

I want to detect motion and tamper conditions using a micro controller, e.g. Arduino Mega etc., but hooking up the two switch circuits for each motion detector directly to the controller board is messy and I'd run out of pins really fast.

[There are shift register tutorials on the Arduino website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/ShiftIn) but I don't think the example circuit there is good. Because my wire lengths are super long I have to consider, among other things, radio interference and I think also cross-talk because of the 12V lines being next to the switch circuit lines. Also I think running 5V across the wire and using pull-down resistors like in the linked tutorial is not good due to risk of a short circuit, so I thought it is better to do it the other way around with pull-up resistors.

I have never designed a PCB before, but I read up on example circuits on the Internet and came up with the schematic below.

[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB Layout]

The idea is that I get a batch of these boards made and can put a them in a plastic housing and daisy chain the power across using the JST-2P connectors. Three wires from each board go to the micro controller which polls the individual shift registers in a loop to determine all the 25 motion detector states. The motion detectors get their two switch circuits connected with screw-on terminals at the bottom of the board.

My questions:

- Does this circuit make sense the way it is designed? Can it be improved further?
- Is the routing sensible or is there something professional engineers would not do? The "auto router" created something that looked like a toddler scribbling with crayons so I gave up on using it.
- I had to put VIAs under RU* surface-mount resistors, is that allowed at all?
- Is there a way to "test-run" circuit boards before ordering them other than building the schematic on a breadboard?

Any advice or hints are appreciated.

Comment: A few observations:
Via-in-pad is expensive and 100% not necessary for your board.
An I2C I/O expander will let you expand easier than daisy-chaining a bunch of shift registers and most have an interrupt output that flags when any input changes state.
Decouple the power supply at your chip (and probably also where the power enters the board).

Comment: @jsotola Yes of course that's a very valid solution but in my case I would like to know the state of each detector. There are also window open/close contacts, etc. in the final setup, but I didn't want to pad out my question with an even larger wall of text.

Comment: @vir Thank you for your feedback. I will redo the board using an MCP23017 and add decoupling capacitors after power into the board and before the chip to remove any line noise. I'll also try to get rid of the VIAs when redoing the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd suggest you look at commercial alarm circuit boards to see how they solve the problem. This saves you having to re-learn important lessons. Whilst the problem appears simple, the reality is somewhat more involved due to:

1. Lightning
2. EMI (electro-magnetic interference)

Generally you'll find professional systems start with a MOV (metal oxide varistor) from each input and power rail to earth. Something like a 7mm 14VAC disk MOV.
This is your front-line defense. The MOV should take care of the majority of an induced Lightning pulse and make sure that you use fat tracks. How fat? 120+ thou (3+mm). Make sure your earth is super fat - a coper fill even and have s screw lug or similar so you can attach an earth. Make the path as sort and direct as possible - you want to ensure the transient will want to follow the path and not jump over (due to high voltages) to a less protected part of your circuit.

Next is you pull up resistor - don't go for the smallest resistor as a lightning strike can induce a voltage that will happily jump across the resistor making it appear as a piece of wire. A through hole resistor give you this distance, whereas with SMT you might want to choose a 1206 sized part or larger. Similarly with your series resistor and filter capacitor.

Have some physical distance on your pcb for these components - don't try to cram them into the smallest space.

Some hints on pcb design:

1. don't use the auto place or auto router! The results are usually bad.
2. For connectors and other items where you need physical strength, make the pads larger. How large? Thats the challenge! If you've got the space, then use it! It also can make soldering easier, so use that as a guide - is there enough pad to put your soldering iron tip onto it?
3. understand the current carry capacity of your pcb tracks. For low level logic signals you can use 8 thou tracks, but for power you'll generally want fat tracks. For 0V, I'll use a copper fill on the bottom of a two-sided pcb.
4. Due to the 0V copper fill on the bottom, try to route everthing else on the top layer. Inevitably, you'll need tracks on the bottom, but try to ensure the copper fill isn't compromised too much.

Prefessional alarm systems use 'END OF LINE' resistors. This allows you to encode for states on two wires - short,open,tamper and alarm. The common method is to use the ADC (analog to digital converter) to read the voltage and your code determines which state based on the voltage. Analog multiplexers like the 4051 are used to switch the detector inputs.

Rather than use shift registers etc, it makes sense to use a number of microcontrollers - they're cheap and use RS485 communications to talk between baords. Alarm systems don't need high data rates - the detector inputs are filtered so that changes less than a few hundred milliseconds are ignored.
Have a smaller number of inputs on each pcb - 8 or 16 are common numbers. You can expand your system easily if required. PCBs are cheap!

Don't use micro USB connectors to distribute 5volts. They are physically weak. Have your boards run off 12V and have regulators on each pcb. Regs like the Recom R785 series make you life easier. There's also similar devices from companies like Mornsun.

Comment: Thank you. I will redo the board without a shift register and instead attempt it with an MCP23017, also taking your hints into consideration.

Would lightning be much of an issue when considering that there will be a 5V PSU for the logic components and a 12V PSU exclusive to the detectors and both these PSUs are plugged into a UPS that includes a line conditioner?

I don't intend to use USB connectors. The JST PH 2.0 2P connectors I picked are the same that most electronics use to connect LiPo batteries. I figured they are suitable and safe for max. 300mA at 5V.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using I2C for inter board communications simply because of its propensity to lock up. Timeouts can mitigate this, but I would simply not use I2C. Lightning is very much an issue.  A ups and line conditioner will have no effect on voltages induced via the detector wiring.